# Using tensorflow 1.15, is there a way to load a keras model created in python in C++ and make a prediction?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, keras

I have created a keras model in Tf 1.15, and I want to be able to make predictions using that model in C++. In python I would simply load the model and run `model.predict(input)`, but I am not sure if that translates easily to C++ and what the commands are. I am currently saving the model using `model.save(save_path)`. Would that cause any issues? Are there any significant conversions I need make? Thank you for any help.